# Trying to setup ADB wireless, stuck at "adb tcpip 5555"

Tags: android, adb

I used to be able to setup wireless ADB no problem (plug in, adb tcpip 5555, adb connect ),  now it gets stuck indefinitely during the "adb tcpip 5555" command. Wired adb still works fine, so does setting up wireless ADB through apps in play store, just not via cmd. Between wireless working and now not working, I did a bunch of things so any of them may or may not be the problem:

1) Reformatted computer (Same OS)

2) Redownloaded the SDK needed for Android Development

3) Went from ParanoidAndroid to GPE on my HTC One.

Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Try adb connect IP_ADDRESS

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate what apps do with these steps on your device with root and android terminal emulator:

```
$ adbd stop
$ setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
$ adbd start
```

Then use `adb connect XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` where `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is your ip address found from:

```
$ ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/inet addr/ {print $2}' | cut -d: -f2
```

You can check if your connection is establed using `netstat | grep 5555`. You should see a tcp entry with your ip address and port for adb connectivity.

Comment: Hi. I believe right now (at least in newer Android version) You can make it work without having root access by executing `setprop ctrl.restart adbd` after `setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555`. It worked for me anyway I think. Thank You for the answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted then it is very simple to establish a wireless connection, you don't even need a USB cable. Download this app from Google Play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en

It worked for me at least, and as can be seen from the app rating it works for almost all.

Answer (score 0):

-----Enter the command adb kill-server at command prompt-----

C:>adb kill-server

-----Enter the command adb devices-----

C:>adb devices

List of devices attached

daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

daemon started successfully

DeviceID      device

-----DeviceID is the unique ID of connected device-----

-----Enter the command adb tcpip 5555-----

C:>adb tcpip 5555

restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

-----will see the response as given above -----

-----Enter the command adb connect 1.1.2.2-----

-----1.1.2.2 is the mobile device IP-----

C:>adb connect 1.1.2.2

connected to 1.1.2.2:5555

-----will see the response as given above -----

-----Now u can use 1.1.2.2:5555 ID as wireless to connect device-----